# Maximum sum such that no two elements are adjacent. How do I set the constraint?

Tags: c++

Hackerrank question:

> Till now, there have been no COVID-19 cases identified in the country XYZ. Scientists and researchers there have conducted a research and discovered that, in a street with houses (imagine that the houses are only on one side of the street, the other side is empty), if residents in a house were affected with the novel Coronavirus, there is a high probability for the houses on either side of that house to be diagnosed with Coronavirus as well. This will result in an extremely high possibility for almost all the houses be affected by COVID-19.
>
> Hearing this, the President of the country XYZ has decided to execute (kill) residents in some houses to save more people from that street.
>
> You will be given an input string, containing the number of residents in adjacent houses for a specific street. Your task to find the maximum number of residents that can be saved from getting infected by COVID-19.
>
> Input Format : Input string contains a set of integers separated by a space
>
> Constraints : 1 < houses in a lane <=1000.
>
> Output Format: Print the maximum number of residents that can be saved from getting infected by COVID-19.
>
> Sample input: 3 5 3 4 3 6
>
> Output : 15

I passed the testcase 0 but still overall my answer is wrong.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    #include<sstream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        string input = "3 5 3 4 3 6", temp="";
        int length = input.size(), i,j,scount=0,ncount=0,incl,excl=0,excl_new,temp2;
        char ch;

        for(i=0; i<length;i++)
        {
            ch = input[i];
            if(ch == ' ')
            {
                ++scount;
            }
            if(isdigit(ch))
            {
                ++ncount;
            }
        }

        if(ncount>1 && scount<=1000)
        {
            for(i=0; i<length;i++)
            {
                ch = input[i];
                if (isdigit(ch))
                {
                    temp += ch;
                }
                else
                {
                    stringstream(temp)>>incl;
                    j = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            temp ="";
            for(i=j; i<=length;i++)
            {
                ch = input[i];
                if (isdigit(ch))
                {
                    temp += ch;
                }
                else if(temp=="")
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    stringstream(temp)>>temp2;
                    temp ="";
                    if(incl>excl)
                        excl_new = incl;
                    else
                        excl_new = excl;
                    incl = excl + temp2;
                    excl = excl_new;
                }
            }
            if(incl>excl)
                cout<<incl;
            else
                cout<<excl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a link to this problem on Hackerrank?

Answer (score 0):

From the input given in your problem statement, it looks like you can simply calculate the sum of all the residents at even and odd houses separately; and, then get the maximum of the two. That'll give you the number of the residents in the houses that are not adjacent.

For example:

```
3 5 3 4 3 6    // Residents in adjacent houses
3 _ 3 _ 3 _    // Sum: 9
_ 5 _ 4 _ 6    // Sum: 15

Maximum: 15    // Maximum of the two sums
```

As indicated in the question that the input string would be a set of integers separated by a *space*, one way could be to use `std::istringstream` for extracting the integers. If the input is through STDIN, `std::cin` would be enough. The rest would be the calculation of the sum of all the integers at even and odd locations; and the maximum of the two sums.

Here's an example for your reference ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/4nMo5w)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

auto calculateResidents( const std::string& input )
{
    auto evenSum {0u};
    auto oddSum  {0u};

    std::istringstream iss{ input };

    for ( auto i{0u}, n{0u}; iss >> n; ++i )
    {
        ( i & 1 ) ? oddSum += n : evenSum += n;
    }

    return std::max( evenSum, oddSum );
}

int main()
{
    const std::string input{ "3 5 3 4 9 6" };
    std::cout << calculateResidents( input );
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
15
```

This is in no way a ready-made solution for your problem! Use this example as a guideline only! You need to figure out your own algorithm according to your own understanding of the C++ language facilities. There might be some corner cases that you need to take care of. Good luck!

Comment: I don't think the question is specifically about every other house. How about a scenario like "4 1 4 1 4 6 2 2 4". Adding odds give 16, evens 10 but if you add 4+4+6+4 you get a score of 18.

Comment: @Pzc: I'm waiting for the OP to respond with a link to test this. It was just my understanding of the problem. There might be some corner cases though. But, you are welcome to use that `live` link above the code to run different scenarios. I just ran it with the input you provided and it gave me `18`. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/l9OHiK).

Comment: Ah yes, my bad with the input. Removing the last 4 in my example ("4 1 4 1 4 6 2 2") gives odds 14, evens 10 and mix 4+4+6+2=16. Live link picks 14. But yeah, clarification would indeed be nice.

Comment: @Pzc: Right. Yup. That is a valid use-case and there could be more like this. Let that be an exercise for the OP. ;) BTW, you can post a solution for that if you want to.

Comment: As per the input in my question the trick adding odd inputs and even inputs worked but try input like 10 20 30 5 12 37 2 17 70 sum of the odd input is 124 and sum of the even output is 79 but consider this 70 + 37+ 30 + 10 brings 147.

Comment: @JayarajRohan: Yup. That's what the previous comments are about on this answer. Please add the problem link in your question.

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/homealone2020/challenges/covid-19-1-2

Comment: @JayarajRohan: 404. Looks like it's from a contest with no public access.

Comment: sorry about that but i think i included everything in my post and can you tell what is the particular part you couldn't understand?

Comment: @JayarajRohan: The problem statement is clear. I wanted to observe all the test cases myself. Not an issue. If you could add some test cases in your question that'd be great.

Comment: no we can't see what are the test cases they only show whether the test cases are passed or not.

Comment: @JayarajRohan: I looked at this [thread](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-such-that-no-two-elements-are-adjacent/) and it looks you're already following this one. I've changed my code accordingly. Can you test [this](https://godbolt.org/z/6bQUJ8) one?